# Numpy time efficient way to combine two cases

Tags: python, numpy

Let's describe the problem.
For example, I have the matrix shape of (3,2,4)

```
price_path = np.array([[[100, 130, 150, 160],
                        [100, 130, 150, 160]],

                      [[100,  80,  70,  60],
                       [100,  80,  70,  60]],

                      [[100, 110,  60,  80],
                       [100, 110,  60,  80]]])
```

In this context, 3 means the number of price path simulations (like in Monte-Carlo Framework)
2 means the num of financial assets
4 means the num of time periods (in days).

Financial asset has quantities:

```
quantites = np.array([[ 1],
                      [-2]])
```

Also, for financial asset a special characteristic is introduced for, it's called daily settlement.

I have two functions for two cases:

- If all assets have daily settlement feature then it returns:

```py
> quantities * (price_paths[:, :, 1:] - price_paths[:, :, :-1])
```

```
[[[ 30,  20,  10],
  [-60, -40, -20]],

 [[-20, -10, -10],
  [ 40,  20,  20]],
    
 [[ 10, -50,  20],
  [-20, 100, -40]]])
```

- If all assets does not have that feature then:

```py
> quantities * price_paths[:, :, 1:]
```

```
[[[ 130,  150,  160],
  [-260, -300, -320]],

 [[  80,   70,   60],
  [-160, -140, -120]],
    
 [[ 110,   60,   80],
  [-220, -120, -160]]])
```

**Is there time efficient (numpy) way to make a function work for cases where not all assets have daily settlement?**
**For example: first asset has it, the second one has not it, then the function returns:**

```
[[[  30,   20,   10],
  [-260, -300, -320]],

 [[ -20,  -10,   -10],
  [-160, -140, -120]],
    
 [[  10,  -50,   20],
  [-220, -120, -160]]])
```

Comment: How does one determine that an asset has a daily settlement? What is the actual value that sets this? You only mention that "financial asset a special characteristic is introduced for, it's called daily settlement.". But that is not a value: it's just a mention that it exists.

Comment: Actually we define that by tuple `ds = [True, False]`

Comment: That is a two-element list. Surely you can do that with a simple if-elif-else statement?

Comment: I know, but for 100 000 simulations it might be so long. And assets in portfolio are not always two

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. With a bit of trial and error, I have now come up with a potential solution. Whether it'll be fast enough, is up to you to measure and decide.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand you correctly, but my result seems to be what you want (for this small test case at least).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> price_paths = np.array([[[100, 130, 150, 160],
...                         [100, 130, 150, 160]],
...
...                       [[100,  80,  70,  60],
...                        [100,  80,  70,  60]],
...
...                       [[100, 110,  60,  80],
...                        [100, 110,  60,  80]]])
>>> quantities = np.array([[ 1],
...                       [-2]])
>>> ds = [True, False]
>>> # Let's make sure `ds` is an array as well
>>> ds = np.array(ds)
```

Note that the second equation is just the first part of the first equation. So you need to have `quantities` zero for those parts where `ds` is `False`.

Define a helper variable that is duplicatie of `quantities`, but with the relevant values set to `0` where `ds` is `False`.

```
>>> quantities2 = quantities * ds.reshape(-1, 1)
>>> quantities2
array([[1],
       [0]])
```

Now split the first equation into two parts that are added together:

```
>>> quantities * price_paths[:, :, 1:] - quantities2 * price_paths[:, :, :-1]
array([[[  30,   20,   10],
        [-260, -300, -320]],

       [[ -20,  -10,  -10],
        [-160, -140, -120]],

       [[  10,  -50,   20],
        [-220, -120, -160]]])
```